# TypeError: element.loader.split is not a function

Tags: javascript, webpack

With the configuration defined below, an error was thrown to the console when `webpack` was run:

> TypeError: element.loader.split is not a function

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: {
    chiffr: getEntrySources([
      './src/index',
    ]),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: ['react-hot', 'jsx'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    }],
  },
};
```

Installed Node modules:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "15.2.0",
  "react-dom": "15.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-eslint": "6.1.0",
  "eslint": "2.13.1",
  "eslint-config-airbnb": "9.0.1",
  "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "1.5.3",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "5.2.2",
  "jsx-loader": "0.13.2",
  "node-sass": "3.8.0",
  "react-hot-loader": "1.3.0",
  "webpack": "1.13.1",
  "webpack-dev-server": "1.14.1"
}
```

What's the source of the error and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs because the `loader` attribute for the first loader expects a String not an Array; an Array does not have a `split` method.

Each object in the `module.loaders` attribute of the config expects a String set to the `loader` property. From the [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders):

> **module.loaders**
>     An array of automatically applied loaders.
>
> Each item can have these properties:
>
> test: A condition that must be met
>     exclude: A condition that must not be met
>     include: A condition that must be met
>     loader: A string of “!” separated loaders
>     loaders: An array of loaders as string

Since the configuration requires an Array of loaders, the key should be set to `loaders` instead:

```
module: {
  loaders: [{
    test: /\.js$/,
    // Change the key to 'loaders' for an Array of loaders
    loaders: ['react-hot', 'jsx'],
    include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    exclude: /node_modules/,
  }],
},
```